# IE6 - Elements pop in and out

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

http://img520.imageshack.us/img520/6951/723200995413pm.png

As you can see from the image above, in IE6 divs with essentially the same markup and css sometimes pop in and out of position, as I move the mouse around. I do not have any hover effect in them ...

**HTML Markup**

```
<pre>&lt;div class=&quot;block yellow shieldalert&quot;&gt;
  &lt;div class=&quot;content&quot;&gt;
    &lt;h6&gt;Shield Alert&lt;/h6&gt;
    &lt;pre class=&quot;brush:xhtml&quot;&gt;
    &lt;!-- content for syntax highlighting --&gt;
    &lt;/pre&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
```

**CSS (partial)**

```
<pre>div.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 32px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border-color: #d7d7d7;
}

div.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px 10px 1px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

div.yellow {
  background-color: #fff67f;
  border: 1px solid #e6e089;
}
div.yellow div.content {
  background-color: #fffde0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e089;
}

div.yellow h1, div.yellow h2, div.yellow h3, div.yellow h4, div.yellow h5, div.yellow h6 {
  color: #cfcd13;
}

div.shieldalert {
  background-image: url(../images/div/info-shieldalert.png);
}</pre>
```

Comment: CSS :hover doesn't work for anything except anchor tags in IE6 anyway. Do you have any JS?

Comment: js. yes but ... does it matter? i dont think any js modifies/works on the divs affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also found that when you have trouble with stuff flickering / peek-a-boo(ing) it is sometimes helpful to put a height:1%; on it. I often make a rule:

```
* html .ie6-fix
{
     height: 1%;
}
```

And then apply the class to anything that's giving me trouble in ie6. This will be ignored in browsers besides internet explorer anyways.

Comment: yes. height: 1%; solves it. i noticed that sometimes, setting width/height to 1% may cause the element to really become smaller. sometimes it dont. when does it make elements smaller? when does it not?

Comment: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html

Check out that link. The bug occurs when you don't actually put a height on certain elements and instead the height is inferred. It's hard to say when the rule will actually affect the height and when it won't but you can always override the 1% rule with a more specific rule. As long as you give the element a height explicitly the same effect will be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the [IE6 peek-a-boo](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html) bug?

Try including this script: [Dean Edwards' IE8.js script](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). It fixes the peek-a-boo bug and several others, and makes IE6 (and IE7) behave much more like an up-to-date browser. [Have a look at the list of things it fixes/implements](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html).

You need to include `ie7-squish.js` to fix the IE6 bugs, by the way.